# Flutter Web - Send Emails with EmailJS works but how to add an attachement (PDF)

Tags: json, flutter, email, post

so i managed to send emails via EmailJS but how can i add an attachment?

i created a pdf like this:

```
Uint8List pdfInBytes = await pdf.save();
  final blob = html.Blob([pdfInBytes], 'application/pdf');
  final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
  anchor = html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
    ..href = url
    ..style.display = 'none'
    ..download = 'pdf_' + timestamp.toString() + '.pdf';
  html.document.body!.children.add(anchor);
```

so i have the pdf as a blob file (opening it via blob url works) but how can i attach it to the mail?

thanks!

i tried this:

```
  final response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: json.encode({
        'service_id': serviceId,
        'template_id': templateId,
        'user_id': userId,
        'attachments': {'test.pdf': blob},
        'template_params': {
          'user_name': name,
          'user_email': email,          
          'user_message': message,
        }
      }));
```

this gives me the following exception:

`Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of '_Future<Blob>'`

// EDIT

update!

i converted my blob to base64 but emailjs api still won't accept my request (Statuscode 400 - The API parameters are invalid)..

emailjs doc:

[image: emailjs doc]

this is my request:

[image]

when i paste my content data to base64 decoder it gives me the pdf content so it should be fine?!

[image]

what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronization issue.
The Future takes time to read your data, and your program isn't waiting for it to finish. The correct implementation is to only execute the `HTTP POST` after the Future loads the PDF.

```
void runMyFuture() {
    readPDFBlob().then((blob) {
        // Run the code here using the value
        // http.post( ... )
    });
}
```

Comment: i thought 'await' makes sure everything is done before posting?!

Answer (score 0):

All your template parameters, including attachments, must be inside [the template_params](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/rest-api/send/).

```dart
    final response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: json.encode({
        'service_id': serviceId,
        'template_id': templateId,
        'user_id': userId,
        'template_params': {
          'user_name': name,
          'user_email': email,          
          'user_message': message,
          'attachments': base64URI,
        }
      }));
```